# building kendo ui with gulp

Tags: kendo-ui, gulp

I am attempting to integrate `kendo` into my site, and one of the processes I need to do is to build it with `gulp.js`. I notice that kendo already has `grunt.js` support, but that isn't what I am using; I tried to reverse engineer its own `gruntfile.js` to figure out the right way to do this, but have met with nothing but failure.

In general, the main thing I cannot figure out is the order to assemble the files in. I simply cannot find this anywhere. There are so many, I only know that `kendo.core.js` needs to be first. Is there a list somewhere of the correct order to put all of the other `kendo.*.js` files in to get the same result as `kendo.all.js` that I would get from the CDN?

References:

## [kendo ui gruntfile.js](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: haven't tested this, but I would try in the order they're in here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.ui.core.js (the complex widgets that are part of commercial and not listed there, e.g. the grid, should go last)

Comment: guh.. I feel so stupid. I searched through the kendo sites for hours and hours, and meticulously tried to reverse engineer the gruntfile. I don't know how I overlooked this in such an obvious place.

Comment: Hey, your comment worked for me. Can you post it as an actual answer so I can award credit?

Comment: @Ciel how do you manage the css and the paths to the assets using **gulpjs**? (did you generate one big css file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try in the order they're listed in [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.ui.core.js) (the complex widgets that are part of commercial and not listed there, e.g. the grid, should go last).